# ERR IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-20.3-py2.7.egg'

Tags: python, heroku, flask, ibm-cloud

I try to deploy a Flask app in python (python 2.7.10). 
It is a very easy app with requirements.txt

- Flask==0.10.1
- distribute==0.6.27
- setuptools==20.3
- scipy==0.17
- matplotlib==1.5.1
- pickleshare==0.7.2
- scikit-learn==0.17.1
- numpy==1.11.1

The app worked locally. 
I now try to deploy it on IBM Bluemix and after pasting the command

```
sudo cf push app
sudo cf logs predict_population --recent
```

I have this error:

```
ERR Command "/app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-bPyipf/distribute/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-RwvTnr-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-bPyipf/distribute/ 2016-09-11T14:09:39.93+0300
[STG/0]      ERR Traceback (most recent call last): 2016-09-11T14:09:39.93+0300
[STG/0]      ERR   File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/pip", line 9, in <module> 2016-09-11T14:09:39.93+0300
[STG/0]      ERR     load_entry_point('pip==8.1.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')() 2016-09-11T14:09:39.93+0300
[STG/0]      ERR   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 217, in main 2016-09-11T14:09:39.93+0300
[STG/0]      ERR     return command.main(cmd_args) 2016-09-11T14:09:39.93+0300
[STG/0]      ERR   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 246, in main 2016-09-11T14:09:39.93+0300
[STG/0]      ERR     pip_version_check(session) 2016-09-11T14:09:39.93+0300
[STG/0]      ERR   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/outdated.py", line 102, in pip_version_check 2016-09-11T14:09:39.93+0300
[STG/0]      ERR     installed_version = get_installed_version("pip") 2016-09-11T14:09:39.93+0300
[STG/0]      ERR   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 848, in get_installed_version 2016-09-11T14:09:39.93+0300
[STG/0]      ERR     working_set = pkg_resources.WorkingSet() 2016-09-11T14:09:39.93+0300
[STG/0]      ERR   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 626, in __init__ 2016-09-11T14:09:39.93+0300
[STG/0]      ERR     self.add_entry(entry) 2016-09-11T14:09:39.93+0300
[STG/0]      ERR   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 682, in add_entry 2016-09-11T14:09:39.93+0300
[STG/0]      ERR    for dist in find_distributions(entry, True): 2016-09-11T14:09:39.93+0300
[STG/0]      ERR   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2080, in find_eggs_in_zip 2016-09-11T14:09:39.93+0300
[STG/0]      ERR     if metadata.has_metadata('PKG-INFO'): 2016-09-11T14:09:39.93+0300
[STG/0]      ERR   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1610, in has_metadata 2016-09-11T14:09:39.93+0300
[STG/0]      ERR     return self.egg_info and self._has(self._fn(self.egg_info, name)) 2016-09-11T14:09:39.93+0300
[STG/0]      ERR   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1968, in _has 2016-09-11T14:09:39.93+0300
[STG/0]      ERR     return zip_path in self.zipinfo or zip_path in self._index() 2016-09-11T14:09:39.93+0300
[STG/0]      ERR   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1848, in zipinfo 2016-09-11T14:09:39.93+0300
[STG/0]      ERR     return self._zip_manifests.load(self.loader.archive) 2016-09-11T14:09:39.93+0300
[STG/0]      ERR   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1791, in load 2016-09-11T14:09:39.93+0300
[STG/0]      ERR     manifest = self.build(path) 2016-09-11T14:09:39.93+0300
[STG/0]      ERR   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1764, in build 2016-09-11T14:09:39.93+0300
[STG/0]      ERR     with ContextualZipFile(path) as zfile: 2016-09-11T14:09:39.93+0300
[STG/0]      ERR   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1813, in __new__ 2016-09-11T14:09:39.93+0300
[STG/0]      ERR     return zipfile.ZipFile(*args, **kwargs) 2016-09-11T14:09:39.93+0300
[STG/0]      ERR   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 756, in __init__ 2016-09-11T14:09:39.94+0300
[STG/0]      ERR     self.fp = open(file, modeDict[mode]) 2016-09-11T14:09:39.94+0300
[STG/0]      ERR IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-20.3-py2.7.egg'
```

Comment: Solved ! Instead of writing                                                                                    if __name__ == "__main__":
 app.run()                                                                                                                Just do                                                                                                              port = os.getenv('PORT', '5000')
if __name__ == "__main__":
 app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=int(port))                                                         and it works !

Answer (score 0):

Solved ! Instead of writing if name == "main": app.run() Just do port = os.getenv('PORT', PORT_NUMBER) if name == "main": app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=int(port)) and it works !